# How do I enable Direct Boot feature on Nexus 6 running Android N Preview 1?

Tags: encryption, 7.0-nougat, direct-boot

According to [these instructions](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/direct-boot.html#testing) there should be a "Convert to file encryption" option in Developer settings, but it's not there on my Nexus 6 running stock N Preview 1.  When I try to search for it in the Settings app, it does show up:

[image]
*[click for larger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzgExl.png)*

Unfortunately, tapping on it simply brings me right back to Developer settings where that option is not found.

The alternative instruction is to reboot to bootloader and issue the `fastboot --wipe-and-use-fbe` command, but it fails with "**fastboot: unknown option -- wipe-and-use-fbe**" error.  I am running the SDK Tools version 25.1.1 rc1, and Platform-tools version 24 rc1 from the preview channel of Android SDK, with latest fastboot utility (version 102d0d1e73de-android).

I performed a complete wipe (system and userdata), and flashed all the [NPC56P](https://developer.android.com/preview/download.html#flash) images manually (bootloader, radio, recovery, system, cache, userdata.)  The phone is encrypted, Screen lock is set to "PIN", and Secure start-up (requiring PIN before boot) is enabled.

Is this feature simply not available in Preview 1 and/or Nexus 6?  How can I enable it?

Comment: Are you sure the `fastboot` you're calling is the one from the new SDK you installed? I've been caught out before by having two `fastboot` binaries of which the older was the first on the path.

Comment: @DanHulme I am fairly certain that I am running the latest preview version of `fastboot`.  The current stable one (rev 23.1) doesn't even have a "--version" switch, whereas the preview one (rev 24 rc1) does, and reports it as "102d0d1e73de-android".  I have only one fastboot.exe installed on this machine, and just in case I navigate to the installation directory in Command Prompt before issuing the commands.

Comment: No idea of Android N. So a very humble opinion. disable system level encryption first and then go for fbe. might work.

Comment: @IftekharAS System-level encryption cannot be disabled on stock Android 6.0 and above.  On Marshmallow and N the phone gets encrypted by default, and the only way to remove encryption is to use a custom kernel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid that in Preview 1 this is only available on the Nexus 5X and the Nexus 6P. In Preview 2, support for the Pixel C is added. No other devices are supported at the moment. Sorry!

Comment: That's a bummer. Any source for this information?

Comment: I'm not sure where it's been publicly stated. But the option only appears in the developer menu if it's supported on the device.

Comment: To be clear: source is me, just now; I'm very closely involved in working on this feature, and I just checked our source tree.

Comment: Thanks for the information, @PaulCrowley. Is the feature going to be rolled out to all devices (that get updated to N) eventually?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely you are using old version of fastboot.Please use newer version of fastboot of Android N.It worked for me.

You can check various option available with your fastboot.
fastboot --help.

--wipe-and-use-fbe                       On devices which support it,
                                           erase userdata and cache, and
                                           enable file-based encryption

But it does not enable file encryption for me after executing the above command.

Comment: I tried this. Was successfully able to --wipe-and-use-fbe but my internal storage was left unencrypted. I encrypted it again from settings > security, and it encrypted. However, this is the usual entire partition encryption and not the file based encryption. Did you get it to work?